# Add together elements from Pandas DataFrame based on timestamp

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to add together elements in the second column from from two dataframes where the time(in the first column) is the same, however the time in each DataFrame is spaced at different intervals. So, in the image below, I would like to add the y values of both lines together:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8VeGv.png)
So where they overlap, the combined value would be at around 3200.

Each dataframe is two columns: first one is time in unix timestamp, and the second column is power in watts, and the spacing between each row is usually 6 seconds, but sometimes more or less. Also, each dataframe starts and ends at a different time, although there is some overlap in the inner portion.
I've added the first few rows for ease of viewing:
**df1:**

```
             time  power
0      1355526770  1500
1      1355526776  1800
2      1355526782  1600
3      1355526788  1700
4      1355526794  1400
```

**df2:**

```
             time  power
0      1355526771  1250
1      1355526777  1200
2      1355526783  1280
3      1355526789  1290
4      1355526795  1300
```

I first though to reindex each dataframe inserting a row for every second across the time range of each df, and then linearly interpolating the power value data between each time. Then I would add together the dataframes by adding the power value where the timestamp matched exactly.
The problem with this method is that it would increase the size of each dataframe by at least 6x, and since they're already pretty big, this would slow things down a lot.
If anyone knows another method to do this I would be very grateful.

Comment: if the dataframe are already aligned on the index, why not just ignore one of the times?

Comment: Yea that could work, but I'm trying to preserve the time information from both dfs, so I would know how much power is being used in total at any given timestamp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a [`merge_asof`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.merge_asof.html#pandas.merge_asof) to align on the nearest time:

```
(pd.merge_asof(df1, df2, on='time', direction='nearest', suffixes=(None, '_2'))
   .assign(power=lambda d: d['power'].add(d.pop('power_2')))
)
```

Output:

```
         time  power
0  1355526770   2750
1  1355526776   3000
2  1355526782   2880
3  1355526788   2990
4  1355526794   2700
```

Comment: That's great, thanks! Could you explain how the lambda function works in that case?

Comment: Also, would that work if the dataframes are different sizes?

Comment: Yes, the left one is used reference, so the two do not need to have the same shape. The lambda is just a fancy way to add a new column referencing the DataFrame itself.

Answer (score 1):

Beyond what the other users have said, you could also consider trying out Modin instead of pure pandas for your datasets if you want another way to speed up computation and so forth. Modin is easily integrated with your system with just one line of code. Take a look here: [Intel® Distribution of Modin](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/developer/tools/oneapi/distribution-of-modin.html#gs.paibd6)